# Geordi's authority in Arsenal of Freedom

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, starfleet-rank

Just watching [The Arsenal of Freedom](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Arsenal_of_Freedom_(episode)), and I thought La Forge was a bit arrogant. I usually like the character, but he was acting like Logan's superior rank meant nothing!

**Can a junior grade lieutenant assume command when there's one person of superior rank (the chief engineer, no less) on board?**

Comment: Are you asking for opinions on Geordi's behavior or about Starfleet procedure?

Comment: Do you want the *Star Trek* answer, or the *real world* answer?

Comment: In the US Navy, Ensigns and Lieutenants jg are Officers Of The Deck  on even the largest ships.

Comment: @RonJohn - You might want to note that Trek is largely based on the *British* naval tradition.

Comment: LaForge didn't assume command, Picard left him in command

Comment: Duplicate of [Can a lower ranking officer (Captain, for example) be in charge of a ship with a higher ranking officer (Commodore, or Rear Admiral) on board?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171579/can-a-lower-ranking-officer-captain-for-example-be-in-charge-of-a-ship-with-a)

Comment: Also - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149823/has-any-command-structure-officer-ever-given-an-order-to-a-superior-in-terms-of/149829#149829

Answer (score 23):

Geordi didn't assume command, he was given command by his superior officer.

> **PICARD:** *Yes. Doctor Crusher, this is the Captain. Meet me in Transporter room three. Mister La Forge, you have command of the
>   Bridge.*
>
> **LAFORGE:** *Aye, sir.*
>
> **PICARD:** *And whatever happens down there, your prime responsibility is to the ship.*

And although Logan has the superior *rank*, that doesn't mean that he can override the wishes of the Captain (by assuming command or attempting to give orders to La Forge) just because Picard is *temporarily* off the ship, any more than Lt. Commander Beverly Crusher can tell him how to run Engineering.

You might also wish to note that *command rank* is entirely in the gift of the Captain [rather than being decided by simple rank](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/178290/20774), hence why Ensign Kim can run the Ops Dept. on the USS Voyager.

Comment: Exactly. The moment the captain tells you you're responsible for the ship, you're put in the captain's position. Rank is quite irrelevant compared to the captain's position.

Comment: He also isn't in his chain of command so if something like that were followed he couldn't give him orders anyway. He could tell him what to do if he were in the engineering section of the ship and was helping out down there, but the rank itself didn't put him above him. In terms of rank they were "cousins" and that's just how it works with that system.